# Why is the "I18n folders" tab not visible in my IntelliJ IDEA "Project Structure" dialog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea

According to IntelliJ IDEA documentation here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-structure-dialog.html

There is supposed to be a *"I18n Folders"* tab visible in the *"Project structure"* dialog.

I have a Ruby on Rails project that I'm developing in *IDEA 2017.3*. The Ruby plugin is installed, Ruby on Rails facet is added to the module, but still no *"I18n Folders"* tab is visible.

Any idea why that might be? I've an issue where IDEA is not detecting some of my locale files and wanted to check if the folders are set up correctly, but I have no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Got a response from JetBrains support:

> Sorry this page looks outdated. There are no such views in Project Tool window.